# Class methods and "Potential leak of an object allocated on line..."

Tags: objective-c, class, memory-leaks, class-method

I have this situation:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSLog(@"Print this: %@", [MyObject classString]);
}

// So in MyObject.m I do
@implementation MyObject

+ (NSString *) classString {
     return [OtherObject otherClassString];   //The Warning "Potential leak..." is for this line
}
@end

// Finally in OtherObject
@implementation OtherObject

+ (NSString *) otherClassString {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
    return result;
}
@end
```

In the beginning, I had a warning for `otherClassString` and for `classString` but with this way for `otherClassString` this work.

Now my problem is in `classString` in the `MyObject`. I tried a lot of things, but this warning is always shown. Can't I call a class method inside a class method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `+otherClassString` creates an object with retain count 1 and returns it. This is used as return value for `+classString` as well.

If your methods don't begin with `init`, `new`, or `copy`, you should return autoreleased objects. Everywhere where yours (as is) are used, they'll be expected to return an autoreleased object.

```
+ (NSString *) otherClassString {
    NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc]
                            initWithString:@"Hello World"]
                            autorelease];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Lol, the solution is put autorelease in the 2 function. Your rule work!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem boils down to this: You have a method which, by the naming conventions, should be returning an autoreleased object but instead it's returning a retained object. That method is `+otherClassString`. Change it to the following:

```
+ (NSString *)otherClassString {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have reproduced your scenario exactly and no errors or warnings occurs. Maybe you have an issue on your header files. Here’s my code (Xcode 4.2 and iOS5):

```
// myObject.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "otherObject.h"

@interface myObject : NSObject

+ (NSString *) classString;
@end
// --------------------------
// myObject.m
#import "myObject.h"
@implementation myObject

+ (NSString *) classString {
    return [otherObject otherClassString];   
}

@end

// otherObject.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface otherObject : NSObject

+ (NSString *) otherClassString;

@end

// otherObject.m
#import "otherObject.h"

@implementation otherObject

+ (NSString *) otherClassString {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
    return result;
}

@end
// --------------------------
```

Comment: Can’t understand the negative vote. If using ARC, autorelease is not needed.

Comment: I didn't vote down your answer, but I can tell you that the warning "Potential leak of an object allocated on line…”" is made by the analyzer which pretty-much only works if you are not using ARC. But to me that's a comment not a down vote.